# Showing there exists a zero transformation between two vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Suppose $V,W$ are both two dimensional vector spaces. Let $f_1,f_2 \dots f_5$ be linear transformations from $V \rightarrow W$. Show there exists choices for real numbers $a_1, \dots, a_5$, which are not all $0$, so that $a_1f_1 + a_2f_2 + a_3f_3 + a_4f_4 + a_5f_5$ is the zero transformation. It makes sense intuitively but I'm not so sure of a rigorous proof.

Essentially we want to show $\exists a_1 \dots a_5$ that the Kernel is all of $V$. So can I essentially just say this can be represented as a matrix so that

$A\begin{bmatrix} 
a_1 \\
a_2 \\ 
a_3 \\
a_4 \\
a_5 
\end{bmatrix}
= 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
0 \end{bmatrix}$

Where $A$ is a $2\times 5$ matrix $a_{i,j}$ represents the image of $f_i$ in the $j^{th}$ dimension of $V$, and since this matrix has rank at most $2$, it must have a nontrivial nullspace. Is this an okay way to show it? I'm not as comfortable with linear independence of linear transformations as I am with independence of vectors themselves.

Comment: Do you know that $\dim\operatorname{Hom}(V,W)=\dim V\cdot \dim W$?

Comment: I suppose that you forgot to add that the five numbers cannot be all equal to $0$.

Comment: Your basic idea of looking at dimensions is good, but what exactly does this $2\times5$ matrix and the equation it appears in represent? I would suggest looking at the dimension of the space of linear transformations instead.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen thanks for that information, I didn't know that, nor that the space of linear transformations was a vector space called hom. Can you elaborate on how I may show that, or find a basis for that?

Comment: If you fix a basis, you can represent the linear transformations as matrices. Can you figure out what the dimension of this vector space of matrices is?